# Estoy aprendiendo a programar y no se como declarar una variable que abarque todos los números enteros

Tags: python

Hola que tal buenas tardes, estoy aprendiendo python y se me ocurrió hacer un ejercicio en el que le pida al usuario ingresar su nombre, apellido y edad para saber si pueden ingresar a un bar, el código me corre bien el único problema que tengo es que no me permite hacer un break si el usuario digita un numero en nombre o apellido, estuve buscando una forma de hacerlo y no he podido si me ayudan en esto se los agradeciera un montón.

Acá dejo mi código:

```
primero = input('ingrese su nombre: ')
try:
primero = str(primero)
except:
primero = int
if primero == int:
print('el dato ingresado no es valido')
exit()

segundo = input(' ingrese su apellido: ')
 try:
segundo = str(segundo)
except:
segundo = int
 if segundo == int:
print(' el dato ingresado no es valido')
exit()

edad = input('ingrese su edad: ')
try: 
edad = int(edad)

except:
edad = 'chanchito feliz'
if edad == 'chanchito feliz':
print('el dato ingresado no es valido')
exit()

if edad >= 18:
 print('Puedes ingresar al bar ')
elif edad <18:
print('No puedes ingresar al bar ')
```

Comment: Se parte buscando :3 Quieres validar que un ingreso no contenga números ?? Buscamos validar entrada sin numeros y empezamos a revisar, [primer link](https://codingornot.com/08-python-validar-entradas-ejemplos), [segundo link](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/algoritmos-python/capitulo-12/validaciones) Y luego los ponemos a prueba. Si por alguna razón falla, y al revisar no encontramos el error, vamos a StackOverflow a preguntar que hicimos mal.

Comment: Acá te dejo otra por si acaso: [Python para principiantes - 
6.3. Métodos de Validación](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-6/metodos-de-validacion) - Esta contiene lo que buscas ;)

Answer (score 4):

Mírate el método [str.isnumeric()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isnumeric-application/)

Es un método, en el cual, le pasas una string y si es un número te devuelve True, en el caso contrario te devuelve false.

**Ejemplo:**

```
nombre = input("Dame nombre: ")
if nombre.isnumeric():
    exit()
```

Espero haberte ayudado!